# Generation query when the ManyToMany relationship is used by Spring Data Jpa project

Tags: java, spring, many-to-many, jpql, spring-data-jpa

I've the following entities mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="books2categories",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="book_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="category_id"))
    Collection<Category> categories;
```

...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="categories")
    private Collection<Book> books;
```

BookRepository interface is looked:

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT b FROM Book b INNER JOIN b.categories c WHERE c IN (:categories)")
    List<Book> findByCategories(Collection<Category> categories);
```

Please fix me if I'm wrong in the query itself. 
When I run test for the `findByCategories` method, I'm getting the error:

> testFindByCategories(com.savdev.springmvcexample.repository.JpaBookRepositoryTest):
>   org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of
>   declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are
>   1-based! Position: 1; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of
>   declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are
>   1-based! Position: 1

Which option do I have to resolve it?

And the second, can I debug Spring Data Jpa logic that passes the argument into the query?
I'm getting a proxy returned by Spring Data Jpa, cannot understand where to use break point to debug this behaviour.

UPDATE:
I've fixed it by using `(?1)`:

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Book b INNER JOIN b.categories c WHERE c IN (?1)")
```

instead of

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Book b INNER JOIN b.categories c WHERE c IN (:categories)")
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since parameter names are lost in bytecode, you need to use [@Param](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.3.x/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/Param.html) annotation to indicate the parameter that is mapped as the `:category` variable in your JPQL. So, you code would look like:

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Book b INNER JOIN b.categories c WHERE c IN (:categories)")
List<Book> findByCategories(@Param("categories") Collection<Category> categories);
```

`?1` certainly works, but is probably not as readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the JPA naming convention to solve the issue.

`List<Book> findAllByCategoriesIn(Collection<Category> categories);`

Hope it will help to solve the problem.