# SQL to JPQL select query with IN expression

Tags: sql, database, jpa, jpql

here is my sql :

```
SELECT * FROM files F WHERE F.id in ('1','2','3')
```

Please help me with jpql expression for **in** function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple ! :)
SELECT F FROM files F WHERE id in :ids

Comment: check this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772305/jpql-in-clause-java-arrays-or-lists-sets

Comment: and this one !http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886903/generation-query-when-the-manytomany-relationship-is-used-by-spring-data-jpa-pro